# How to run Selenium-Grid on CloudFoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

Did anyone run Selenium-Grid on CloudFoundry with routing provided by Gorouter?

According to the ["Selenium-Grid Documentation"](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) we can pass the hub address to a node instance like that:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar \ 
  -role node \
  -hub http://myhub.cf/grid/register
```

but this node registers yourself with the local address and port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have already found a solution to my problem (Selenium v3.14.0).

### Local test based on `selenium-server-standalone`

- Hub

  ```
  java -Xmx640M -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -debug
  ```
- Node

  ```
  java -Xmx640M -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -debug \
    -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register \
    -port 8080 -remoteHost http://localhost:8080
  ```

### CloudFoundry manifests based on docker

https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium/

#### Hub

```
---
applications:
- name: selenium-hub
  docker:
    image: selenium/hub
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  disk_quota: 1G
  routes:
  - route: selenium-hub.mycf.cloud
  env: 
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx640M"
    GRID_DEBUG: false
    # Max "browser" sessions a grid can handle
    GRID_MAX_SESSION: 5
```

#### Nodes

```
---
applications:
- name: selenium-node-chrome-1
  docker:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  disk_quota: 1.5G
  routes:
  - route: selenium-node-chrome-1.mycf.cloud
  env: 
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx640M"
    GRID_DEBUG: false
    HUB_HOST: selenium-hub.mycf.cloud
    HUB_PORT: 80
    NODE_PORT: 8080
    REMOTE_HOST: http://selenium-node-chrome-1.mycf.cloud:80
    # Max "browser" sessions a node can handle. Default determined by configuration type.
    NODE_MAX_SESSION: 5

- name: selenium-node-firefox-1
  docker:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  disk_quota: 1.5G
  routes:
  - route: selenium-node-firefox-1.mycf.cloud
  env: 
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx640M"
    GRID_DEBUG: false
    HUB_HOST: selenium-hub.mycf.cloud
    HUB_PORT: 80
    NODE_PORT: 8080
    REMOTE_HOST: http://selenium-node-firefox-1.mycf.cloud:80
    # Max "browser" sessions a node can handle. Default determined by configuration type.
    NODE_MAX_SESSION: 5
```

Comment: If you want it to work, raise your hand on: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6627